# Android path to asset txt file

Tags: android, file, path, assets

I'm doing:

`FileReader fin = new FileReader("file:///android_asset/myFile.txt");`

in an Android project and many variations. At runtime I get a file not found exception. The file is present and correct in the assets folder, so my path must be wrong.

What is the absolute path I need here?

Comment: have you considered the fact that the file name is case sensitive?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("myfile.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

Try using the above with FileDescriptors. Seems to be the most foolproof way I've found to gather asset paths.

Comment: @kcoppock: Here Dalvik complains "FileNotFoundException", saying that the file's probably compressed.

Comment: You're SURE it's directly in the assets folder, not a subfolder?

Comment: @kcoppock:It's directly in the assets folder.

Comment: @SK9: I don't think it's what's causing your problem, but I had a typo, it should be `getFileDescriptor()`, not `getDescriptor()`, but I'm assuming you already figured that one out...

Comment: Can you post your trace? According to the docs, FileReader(FileDescriptor) cannot throw FileNotFoundException, and openFd(String) only throws IOException.

Comment: @kcoppock: No problem at all, Eclipse picked up the typo for me. Thank you for following up.

Comment: @kcoppock: See edited question for trace. (Using descriptor.getFileDescriptor()) is also throwing me a java.io.FileNotFoundException (in the first line it says the file is probably compressed). But it's an asset?

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if it's an encoding issue or something with your particular file? Can you try just making a blank text document in your assets folder, and typing your text in there? Then see if you still have the problem.

Comment: user1013512's below answer is the right one, the problem is that android compresses every file except ones like mp3, png... [this blogpost](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/) explains that very well

Comment: I got the same file compressed error trying this with an ini.

Comment: You can tell android not to compress certain file types: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33359656/2832027

Answer (score 19):

```
    InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("terms.txt");
    String textfile = convertStreamToString(is);

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
            throws IOException {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[2048];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                        "UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            String text = writer.toString();
            return text;
    }
```

Comment: That's doesn't worked! textfile is something like this: %PDF-1.5
%���� 54 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 241790/O 56/E 103481/N 7/T  ..................

Answer (score 3):

Can you use something like

```
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("fileName.txt")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing. Using a buffered reader to read line by line is too slow for my needs.

Comment: Then instead of a BufferedReader use a bufferedInputStream.  I would be surprised, however, if the buffered reader / buffered input stream is slowing down your application, since their very existence is to speed us I/O access to OS resources.

Comment: Quick reply - thank you. I'll try this. Reading a text file line-by-line isn't helping, I need to read ahead, but it may not be the only reason. That I want to find out.

Answer (score 3):

Its not reading it because all assets in assets folder are compressed, try changing its extension to .mp3 then read it in, that should stop it from being compressed.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you are using an IDE like Eclipse you may need to do a clean -- or delete the API in the bin directory.  It seems that the assets isn't getting updated when you do a build.

Answer (score 1):

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream fs = am.open("myFile.txt");
```