# android reading from a text file

Tags: android

I have a java class where it reads some data from a text file using a buffered reader and returns that data as a hash map:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FrequencyLoader {

     public FrequencyLoader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        }

        public HashMap<String, Double> loadUnigramFrequencies() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            HashMap<String, Double> unigramFrequencies = new HashMap<String, Double>();
            String line;
            String[] splittedLine;

            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("unigramFrequencies.txt"));

            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                splittedLine = line.split("\\s");


                unigramFrequencies.put(splittedLine[0].trim(), Double.parseDouble(splittedLine[1].trim()));
            }

            return unigramFrequencies;
        }
}
```

I want to use that in my android application but when I create an instance of this class and try to execute the loadUnigramFrequencies() function in the android Activity class I am getting an error that the application has stopped unexpectedly. I am trying to run it on Samsung Galaxy S2. Should the file be placed somewhere in the android project rather than on the disk? if yes then where?

Comment: Could you provide the logcat to help locate the error ? (Window/Show View/Other/Android/LogCat in eclipse or "adb logcat" in the shell)

Answer (score 2):

without a bit of logcat it is a bit trivial.

```
 unigramFrequencies.put(splittedLine[0].trim(), Double.parseDouble(splittedLine[1].trim()))
```

here for instance could be raised a null pointer execption if splittedLine[0] or splittedLine[1] is null, or parseDouble could arise a number format execption

Answer (score 2):

I think the error might well be there :

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("unigramFrequencies.txt"));
```

You should provide an absolute path here and first make sure that the file exists before accessing it *or* handle the exception.

If this file is some final asset, you should place it in your project assets folder and get a filereader from there.

Example (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789325/android-path-to-asset-txt-file)):

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("unigramFrequencies.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

Note that your unigramFrequencies.txt file should be present in your <project>/assets/ directory

Comment: I placed the unigramFrequencies.txt file under assets. I added the following code:
 AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("unigramFrequencies.txt");

         BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor()));

Comment: The error I am getting

09-27 13:37:57.860: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7208): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
09-27 13:37:57.860: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7208):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method)

09-27 13:37:57.860: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7208):     at org.com.SentencesActivity.loadUnigramFrequencies(SentencesActivity.java:97)
09-27 13:37:57.860: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7208):     at org.com.SentencesActivity.onClick(SentencesActivity.java:54)

Comment: What's the size of your file?

Comment: I know it sounds crazy but try this: rename your file from .txt to .png and change your code appropriately. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder/3537114#3537114) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is searching for a needle in the hay stack.

I recommend you to first learn how to use debugging in Android:
http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html

Also some exception handling wouldn't hurt:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Throwing_and_Catching_Exceptions

The following line of code is very wrong, and it seems you don't understand file storage in android:

```
new FileReader("unigramFrequencies.txt")
```

Here it is explained:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html