# How to load text from file to textview

Tags: android, file-io, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android reading from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568795/android-reading-from-a-text-file)

So I need to load text, but I don't know how :( To save text I'm doing this

```
File logFile = new File("sdcard/data/agenda.file");
if (!logFile.exists())
{
    try
    {
        logFile.createNewFile();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
try
{
    //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
    BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
    buf.append(editText1.getText());
    buf.newLine();
    buf.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So, how to load it back by button tap?

Comment: The tiniest amount of searching this forum itself will provide you with your answer.

Comment: I searched it for 2 or 3 hours, really. I found how to write in file, but did not find how to load-all what I found was not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read content of file, for example *.txt - do this...

```
private String GetPhoneAddress() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/reklama/tck.txt");
    if (!file.exists()){
        String line = "Need to add smth";
        return line;
    }
    String line = null;
    //Read text from file
    //StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        line = br.readLine(); 
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }
    return line;
}
```

Then, from activite to set to textview - just do smthing like

```
final TextView tvphone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saved_phone);
    String saved_phone = GetPhoneAddress();
    if (saved_phone.length()>0){
       tvphone.setText(saved_phone);
    }
```

Comment: It works for me with 100%!!!!!!!))))

Comment: so, please look what I have made-It doesn't work :(( http://pastebin.com/9RYhZh4f

Comment: Ok))) is there any error in Log when you press Button???

Comment: In your code you determine private String readf() in Activity @onCreate.... Put it out after determing of buttons and etc... In your code String read = readf();
                       editText1.setText(read);
                  }
           });

Comment: after it there is case ")" - after it you can determine any methods you use in onClickk...

Comment: OR just use Debug.... in your code - place where you want to stop step by step to see what's wrong - place android.os.Debug.WaitforDebug();

Comment: Then by F5 and F6 look what is happening...

Comment: Sorry for delay.  String readf() is not in onCreate, i just not copied } sorry.  So, please look at my code http://pastebin.com/YFq9ysgF    File is not empty. If I wrote it wile program is runnig text in button is just disappearing

Comment: USE DEBUG to find your problem!!! something is wrong with your FULL CODE!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This function will read your whole file, and set it to the parameter `TextView` as text, if this is what you want. Your code is trying to write the `TextViews` content to a file, it's not reading it.

```
public void loadToTextView(TextView textView) throws Exception
{
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(path, "filename.file");
    textView.setText(new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next());
}
```

Be careful, you will need to handle the `Exception`, that this function might throw.

Comment: So, It is not working :( I tup on button and nothing. In file now only word "hello"

Comment: You can see code here http://pastebin.com/gP6Ghggb

Comment: Set a breakpoint here - e.printStackTrace(); - what exception do you get?

Answer (score 1):

This method will read each line into a `StringBuffer`.

Then just call `setText(contentsOfFile)` on your `TextView`.

```
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/mnt/sdcard/agenda.file"));

StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

String line;
while((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    strBuilder.append(line);
}

fileReader.close();

strBuilder.trimToSize();

String contentsOfFile = strBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Code here http://pastebin.com/crBc1VbW  (This code made eclipse with mistakes).

Comment: You should not hard code the sdcard path, and /sdcard/ is definitely wrong.  Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();