# How to create java.io.File class from file inside assets?

Tags: android

How to create java.io.File class from file inside assets ? I have face.jpg in /assets/images/ and I need File to put in call of another function. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789325/android-path-to-asset-txt-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to create java.io.File class from file inside assets ?

You don't, unless you copy the file from assets to a local file. Assets are not files in the filesystem, and so you cannot create `File` objects representing them.