# Using filePath for an xml from assets folder in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to use the filepath of an xml file that exists in the assets folder of android, like this:

```
String filename = "file:///android_asset/test.xml";
FileInputStream fis =  new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
```

`System.out.println("FileInputStream : " + fis);` // here it fails
I get an

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/android_asset/text.xml

error and it does not make sense to me.

I made an apk and opened it then with total commander and the xml is in the assets folder. Do you see a problem in my approach? Thank you.

Comment: you should put your xml into the res/raw/ folder. here's the link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: I think this post helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789325/android-path-to-asset-txt-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the InputStream,

```
InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("test.xml");
```

You can also keep your xml in the `res/xml` folder and just get it working by

```
getResources().getXml(R.xml.test);
```

[`Here`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Resources/XML/) is a complete example for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Assets are accessed using the `AssetManager`, in your case - like this:

```
Context context = ...;
AssetManager assManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = assManager.open("test.xml");
```