# File path from assets in Android not recognized

Tags: android

Do you know why it does not recognize my path?

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(new File("assets/test.xml"));  // tried with "file:///android_asset/test.xml"  
String fileIn = path.getPath();  
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
```

I get a FileNotFound error at the end, the fis variable.

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using filePath for an xml from assets folder in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077302/using-filepath-for-an-xml-from-assets-folder-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getAssets() will return you the asset folder. You get read a file by

```
InputStream in = getAssets().open("test.xml");
```

if you are doing this our of Activity. Then you need to call context.getAssets();