# Access PDF file in assets folder on android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I have seen many question about accessing files in assets folder but can't seem to get a solid answer. I'm working on a application that would extract a text from PDF file thus I'm using iText Library to do that but my problem here is the file pathing of PDF.

I have tried using **assetManager** and assetManager opens that file but i think iText needs the file path so it can open the file by itself, i am not sure but that is my theory.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(<String PDF-file>);
```

then **How do I access the file under assets folder using iText?** if it is not possible is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried to method outlined in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789325/android-path-to-asset-txt-file ?

Comment: well i'm trying but i can not seem to make it work.

Comment: Why not ? Error if any ?

Comment: err.. well im having a problem in displaying the assets path I'm trying to display the path so i will know how the dercriptor works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code to get asset directory for file and use it for pdfreader.

**code:**

```
File f = FileUtils.fileFromAsset(this, "filename.pdf");

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(f.getPath());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get an InputStream object like this

```
AssetManager am = activity.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("test.txt");
```

and then use this constructor

```
public PdfReader(InputStream is)
          throws IOException
```

http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#PdfReader(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: by the legend, on the 7th day the God created debugger

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem my using this:

`reader = new PdfReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.resume));`