# Can't find the file path which created by myself in android source code

Tags: java, android

I am testing something.

I created **assets** folder in packages/apps/Camera/ and added the **test.txt** file in the folder.

But when I accessed the file in the **onCreate()** method according the following code fragment, I found I can't get the file.

```
    File file = new File("/assets/test.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        Log.v("jerikc","read the file");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String tempString = null;
        int line = 1;

        while ((tempString = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            Log.v("jerikc","line " + line + ": " + tempString);
            line++;
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("jerikc","exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            }
        }
    }
```

The log were :

*V/jerikc (3454): read the file*

*V/jerikc (3454): exception*

I think I add the wrong path.("/assets/test.txt") . 
So what's the right path?

**Some other informations:**

Where my real code is a Util Class, there isn't the context. If I add the context, the code structure will have a big change.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789325/android-path-to-asset-txt-file. Maybe will help you

Comment: I think you missed the **.** in your path _"/assets/test.txt"_, how about try this _"./assets/test.txt"_. Here the dot means your current working directory.

Comment: But I have no context in my test class. Because what's my test is a Util , there isn't context. So I can't use the getAssets() method.

Comment: @JinChen I had a try , but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read assets like below

```
AssetManager mAsset = context.getAssets();

InputStream is = mAsset.open("test.txt");
```

Comment: Sorry , my question isn't clear. I can't use the context in my project ,it's just a Util class. Thanks very much. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I dont think you can access assets without context, you can always pass context as a parameter in function

Comment: But how to explain that it's ok when I create a android project independently， not in android source code project .

Comment: you mean you are creating a external library?

Comment: No. It's just a file , not a external library.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the path from assest folder by this way...try this...

```
File file = new File("file:///assets/test.txt");
```

instead of this..

```
File file = new File("/assets/test.txt");
```

Comment: The same as **File file = new File("/assets/test.txt");**