# How to get right path files in android

Tags: java, android

My code is following::

```
Scanner sc = null;
try {
    sc = new Scanner(new File("assets/mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println(e1.toString());
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, logcat show exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

How can I find my file? I tried

`sc = new Scanner(new File("mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt"));`

However, it's still throw `FilenotFoundException`

My file is in folder assets/mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt

and I've try this::

```
private InputStream is;
try {
        is = this.getResources().getAssets().open("mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.toString();
    }
```

I use getAssets to access assets file in android. However, how can I suppose to read text file if I use `InputStream`

Comment: Is all your directories are located in the same project ? if so just give your path as ./assets/mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt..

Comment: @barssala your text file is in asset folder?

Comment: sure, my text file is in assets/mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt

Comment: ./assets/mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt got Exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException:/./asset/mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You try this...Hope it will work

```
sc = new Scanner(new File("file:///android_asset/mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt");
```

Edit try this

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

Copied from here  [Asset folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789325/android-path-to-asset-txt-file)

Comment: Sorry, but i got `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: for more information. java.io.FileNotFoundException:/file:/android_asset/mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the `assets` folder of your Android application as if they were regular files on the file system (hint: they're not). Instead, you need to use [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).Call `getAssets()` on your activity/application context to get the `AssetManager`.

Once you have this, you can use `open("mainmenu/readSourceFile.txt")` to obtain an `InputStream`.

You can now read this `InputStream` like you would any other. [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/description.html) is a great library for working with input and output streams. Depending on how you want to get the data, you could try:

- Read the entire file into a String:

  ```
  try {
      String contents = IOUtils.toString(in);
  } finally {
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
  }
  ```
- Read the entire file into a list of Strings, one per line:

  ```
  try {
      List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(in);
  } finally {
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
  }
  ```
- Iterate through the file one line at a time:

  ```
  try {
      LineIterator it = IOUtils.lineIterator(in, "UTF-8");
      while (it.hasNext()) {
          String line = it.nextLine();
          // do something with line
      }
  } finally {
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
  }
  ```

Comment: I tried `InputStream` and I can open file now. But I don't know how to read text files if I use `InputStream`

Comment: [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/description.html) makes this easy. Download `commons-io-2.4.jar` and add it to your Java Build Path, then you can read the file in one shot: `String mContents = IOUtils.toString(mInputStream)`. This link also shows how to do the same thing "manually" (`InputStream` -> `InputStreamReader` -> `BufferedReader` -> loop) if you don't want to use `IOUtils` for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I noticed that the file should not include the hierarchy. This worked for me if someone had the same issue in future.
`

```
    InputStream is=null;

    try {
        is=activity.getAssets().open("fileInAssets.dat");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Erro while openning hosts file.");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`